# Why do fighter jets pilots use an oxygen mask?

Tags: fighter, oxygen-mask

I always wondered why fighter pilots need to fly with a facemask.
Since the cabin in pressurised wouldn't the oxygen level be the same as in any commercial jet so sufficient for the pilot to remain conscious and aware?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are fighter jet cabins pressurized?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/are-fighter-jet-cabins-pressurized)

Comment: In addition to @TooTea's linked answer, fighter pilots are meant to operate in environments where other fighter pilots try to make holes in each other's aircraft. This could result in no pressure in the cockpit, which would be sad.

Comment: Plus, the oxygen level (percentage based on volume) is just one part of the equation. Oxygen has to be supplied at or above a certain pressure for your lungs and blood cells to absorb it. At sea level pressure, your entire oxygen absorption and transport mechanism would work fine (barring physiological or chemical problems). At 30,000 feet, even 100% oxygen would have a hard time absorbing. It is easier to pressurize a mask versus an entire cockpit in an emergency.

Answer (score 1):

the pressurization system in a fighter plane might be able to furnish 10,000 ft cabin altitude at 30,000 feet, but the pilot would need supplemental oxygen when flying higher than that. In addition, if the cabin is breached above 30,000 ft the pilot would have very little time to get his or her mask on before blacking out, so the mask is worn at all times.

Comment: Exactly. To add to that, I believe the quoted time of useful consciousness at 30,000 feet is under 60 seconds. I am going off of memory for that stat. But, I believe it is correct.

Comment: In that case why bothering with a pressurisation system at all and not saving space/weight engineering studies etc and only giving the pilot a facemask?

Comment: because without pressurization, even breathing 100% oxygen above 20,000 feet is insufficient to keep the pilot awake and alive.